# Sample from Wishart distribution with inverse Scale matrix

Tags: matlab, covariance, random-generation, numerics, wishart-distribution

I tried to model precision matrix in a hierarchical Bayesian setup with Wishart prior given d.f. and inverse scale matrix, and matrix normal likelihood, since it's a conjugate prior, my posterior on the precision matrix $K$ ends up in the form:
$$
K \sim \text{Wishart}(\text{df}, \Lambda^{-1})
$$
Since the dimension of $\Lambda$ is quite big, I do not wish to take the inverse of the matrix and use the built-in sampler. I looked at the source code for Matlab's `wishrnd`, they used [Bartlett decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Bartlett_decomposition) for large dimensions (81+n), which should also work for smaller dimensions albeit its inefficiency.

snips of the code:

```
[n,m] = size(Lambda);
[d,p] = cholcov(Lambda,1);

% Otherwise use the Smith & Hocking procedure
d = eye(size(d)) / d; 
% Load diagonal elements with square root of chi-square variates
a = diag(sqrt(chi2rnd(df-(0:n-1))));

% Load upper triangle with independent normal (0, 1) variates
a(itriu(n)) = randn(n*(n-1)/2,1);
% Desired matrix is D'(A'A)D
x = a(:,1:size(d,1))*d;

a = x' * x;

% --------- get indices of upper triangle of p-by-p matrix
function d=itriu(p)

d=ones(p*(p-1)/2,1);
d(1+cumsum(0:p-2))=p+1:-1:3;
d = cumsum(d);
```

In order to accommodate my needs,i.e. inputing degrees of freedom $df$ and the inverse scale matrix $\Lambda$ I added

```
d = d \ eye(size(d))
```

after the second line, so that I would have the inverse of the cholesky decomp of the inverse scale matrix, in others words, the cholesky decomp of the scale matrix. Then everything should be okay from there ( I hoped).

I tested this by firstly generating a 3 by 3 positive definite matrix:

```
>> test = rand(190, 3); Lambda = test'*test;
>> Lambda

Lambda =

  62.7642   46.4970   45.6662
  46.4970   61.9178   45.4114
  45.6662   45.4114   59.1070b
```

Setting $df = 6$, 100,000 randoms samples were generated and the empirical mean is compare with the first moment of the distribution

```
>> df = 6;
>> sam = 0; for loop = 1:100000 sam = sam + mywishrnd(Lambda,df); end
>> sam/100000
ans =

 0.0956   -0.1069   -0.0689
-0.1069    0.3380   -0.0286
-0.0689   -0.0286    0.3872

>> inv(Lambda)*df

ans =

 0.2647   -0.1118   -0.1187
-0.1118    0.2692   -0.1205
-0.1187   -0.1205    0.2857
```

There is quite a big differences in some entries of the results, but I don't see anything wrong with this theoretically. Is it possibly due to numerical error? Could someone enlighten me on this problem?

Comment: Probably you should have used `d = inv(d')` after the second line instead of `d = inv(d)` (which is equivalent to `d = d \ eye(size(d))`). The problem is that the inverse of $D^{\top}D$ is $D^{-1} \left(D^{\top}\right)^{-1}$.